# A formal term for a list of events that have transpired

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm trying to pick a good name for a concept. We have previously completed actions (e.g., file uploads or admissions approved) and those constitute a list that historically speaking is "what's been up", so to speak.

At the moment, we're using a Swedish term for it and translating that, gives me *history*. However, in the original language, there are two different terms: *historia* and *historik* with slightly different connotation as to how extensive the details presented are.

The former will provide more complete descriptions and connotations, whereas the latter settles merely for a list of events. It's the second one that I'm going for.

Is the term *history* the only I have to go on or is there a better, formal one?

Comment: History is widely used in English for this purpose. People talk about "browser history" or "account history" all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I propose *timeline*.

> [timeline](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/timeline?s=t)
>   1. a linear representation of important events in the order in which they occurred.

Timelines are often depicted as a line with significant events on it, but they can be bulleted lists too. Here is an example from Wikipedia, [Timeline of European exploration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_European_exploration)

[image]

Comment: I upvoted your answer cus it had also included an example :D. And a very nice one, at that :).

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted your answer because we're on the same page... in so many ways!

Comment: Ha, if I could double-vote your comment, I would :D.

Comment: I've upvoted both your replies because I liked the comments. Also, do you or @TeacherKSHuang can imagine a more general term if the ordering isn't chronologically related? In my current situation, it's perfect with *timeline* but I'd like to be prepared for other listings.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It probably exists, but I can only think of vague things at the moment, such as "outline", "list of events", "ordered list", etc. Possibly also _bill of events_ or _record of events_, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Not a single word, but "event log" springs to mind for that.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you're looking for is:

> a timeline.

Looking at definition one, this is:

> [A linear representation of important events in the order in which they occurred](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/timeline),
>
> Dictionary.com

which is essentially:

> a list of events.

What do you think? Is this what you had been looking for?

Answer (score 5):

**History** is certainly an acceptable word. An alternative is **[log](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/log)**:

> *Computers.* any of various chronological records made concerning the use of a computer system, the changes made to data, etc.

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

It's used in some software for a list of what's happened to a file, e.g. Tortoise SVN, see [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).

Comment: I like this answer even better than my own because it's about activities accomplished, which sounds more like what the OP had been looking for ("previously completed actions").